# Trouble using ScrollView in current Grid Layout

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview

I am attempting to create a scrollview within my layout. I would like ideally 4 boxes per page before scrolling through. The problem is that I can't get it to work with my navigation bar at the bottom.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textGrid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="@string/grid_text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<GridLayout
android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_weight="8"
android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
android:columnCount="2"
android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
android:padding="14dp"
android:rowCount="3"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Me"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Me"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView> //this x8

</GridLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I attempt to change to scrollview, the entire preview screen goes blank. Apologies for this code in advance, I'm just starting out with Java.

Comment: Put your whole Gridlayout inside scrollview

Comment: I have attempted that, but when I use </scrollview> at the end after </gridlayout>, the navigation bar jumps to the top of the page.

Comment: I suspect the issue may have to do with my "Contraint Layout" at the top.

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but I can only edit so many times :( Is there an alternative to this line in the navigation bar script? app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" I find when I remove "parent" it does the same thing to the nav bar that occurs when I close off the ScrollView under my grid layout.